# Local storage with Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, local-storage

I have recently begun coding in Redux.

Before Redux with AngularJS it was easy to map models with state using $localstorage. I just can figure out the best way to do that with Redux.

Should I be dispatching and action and ask reducers to read local storage for in my code ?

Or should I allow local storage to be managed with a global object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways.

Just note that for syncing to `localStorage` you need to call `JSON.stringify` which is quite expensive, so please don't do that often and also with large data structures as it might hurt app's performance.

1) **Sync whole Redux** store to Local Storage. You can use existing solution for that eg. https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage

- I would not recommend to sync whole store as you might sync also state which should not be persisted after refresh and also you might make application slower; For better performance you can use `paths` argument in above library or use one of another options.
- To see how you can build such functionality manually, there is great explanation video from Dan https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage

2) Manually build **simple cache middleware** like below, which might catch specific actions you would like to sync with local storage

```
const cacheMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if(action.type !== 'GET_SOMETHING') {
    return next(action);
  }
  const data = getFromLocalstorage();
  if(!data) {
    // Fetch and put to localstorate for later use
    const data = fetchFromServer();
    return next({ type: 'SERVER_RESULT', data });
  }
  return next({ type: 'CACHED_RESULT', data });
};
```

3) If you are using `Redux Thunk` you can perform caching there as you are allowed to have side effects in actions.

You can find more info about Redux middleware here https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware